Is there any book which I can refer to learn about nature of people through their zodiac sign?
There are tons of web pages, reels, and YouTube videos talking something or other about
a character of a person based on their zodiac signs.
I want an authentic source that has a detailed description of the nature/behavior/character of a person based on their zodiac signs. It will be a great help!
Thanks in advance.

(https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-most-authoritative-texts-on-Vedic-Astrology)

@AweKumarJha thanks for the link

Yes dear.
The first and the mother of Jyotish and Vasu and Astronomy is Bhrugu Samhita. The author is Shrila Bhrugu Rishi Himself the son of Lord Brahma.
Note: Kindly study under the blessings and guidance of a spiritual master.

